# DNS Hijacking: tracing the culprit, and preventing future changes

Tags: dns, ethernet, hijack

I recently discovered that my Ethernet settings IPv4 properties, in Advanced settings ([thanks to Karlis](https://superuser.com/questions/1168481/browsers-redirect-to-level3-com-if-domain-does-not-exist)), had two unwanted entries: 82.163.143.157 and 82.163.142.159 which may be related to DSNUnlocker.

1. Does Windows 10 keep a log showing which program made the change?
2. How do I stop other programs changing my DNS? I already have Comodo Internet Security installed

I am very surprised that:

1. Windows does not (a) notify users that a program wants to modify the DNS entries, and gives you the option (b) adds a notification to the message center noting that changes were made.
2. The Ethernet settings IPv4 properties screen does not highlight that there may be more than two DNS addresses, than the two showing.

Comment: Do you have UAC turned off? Windows requires admin privileges to change dns.

Comment: Use a DNS provider that supports `DNSSEC`.  The simplest way is to not run as an Administrator user, and configure your system, to require an Administrator to change the properties of your LAN/WAN adaptor.  "Windows does not (a) notify users that a program wants to modify the DNS entries, and gives you the option (b) adds a notification to the message center noting that changes were made." - Actually it does.

Comment: I have UAC set so that Windows notifies when applications try to make changes to my computer. When I install a program, I get a warning that a program wants to make change, but I have no idea what those changes are. I think that is the problem.

Comment: I think I am running as an Admin user. Where do I "require an Administrator to change the properties of your LAN/WAN adaptor, or is this required by default?